# FormClose inheritance

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm quite new to Delphi (I'm using version 10.1 Berlin), and I'm trying to understand how inheritance works.

Let's say I have 2 forms that have to do the same action when closed. To avoid code duplication, my initial idea was to create a superclass, `TFoobarForm`, that inherits from `TForm`, and then create a procedure `FormClose` like this:

```
procedure TFoobarForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  { Some code }
end;
```

After that, I would like to create 2 forms, let's say `TFooForm` and `TBarForm`, that inherit from `TFoobarForm`.  But I don't know if there's a way to make these new forms to perform the superclass `FormClose` action without having to manually call the procedure from every class that inherits from it.

In the end, what I'm looking for is a way to avoid writing this:

```
procedure TFooForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  inherited FormClose(Sender, Action);
end;
```

for every subclass of `TFoobarForm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have the base class override the virtual `DoClose()` method:

```
type
  TFoobarForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction); override;
  end;

procedure TFoobarForm.DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  { Some code }
  // call inherited to trigger the OnClose event, if it is assigned...
end;
```

Then you don't need to assign an `OnClose` event handler in the derived classes at all (unless they really want to handle the event differently then the base class).